# FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory node, error persiting after change the max-old-space-size

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am building a scraper with nodejs cheerio, puppeteer and building a frontend with create-react-app.

My scraper takes div, p h1,h2... element of a page and for each div it tries to find work with regex.

The goal is to find address on the website but there is no id no class that allow to identify the address so I have to scrape the text content and math with regex. I think maybe those operations are quiet loud but everything was fine since I change some state on my frontend react app and I run again the full app and got the heap out of memory error in my backend terminal.

I tried everything they said on google from people that got the same error. I changed the `--max-old-space-size` to 8092 when running my app and in the `package.json`. Also, in the start script, I changed the node env variable `NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192` in my bash file on my computer but nothing works.

It really slow now when I run my node app and seem to get stuck in the `getScreenshot` function.

I tried to run a small part of my code but it seem a memory is satured and need to clear because seem that I can't run any script with node now.

I updated my node version to 18 but nothing changed.

This is my app code :

```js
// ** app.js **

const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs');


const Excel = require("xlsx");
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios')
const express = require('express')
const {
  Cluster
} = require("puppeteer-cluster");
const app = express();
const PORT = 8000;


app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}))
app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'images')))


app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
  next();
})


// functions
const getLinks = require('./functions/getLinks')
const getScreenShot = require('./functions/getScreenShot')
const getPaths = require('./functions/getPaths')

/// Excel file 

const file = Excel.readFile('./file/occitanie.xlsx');
const sheetName = file.SheetNames;
const data = Excel.utils.sheet_to_json(file.Sheets[sheetName[0]], {
  defval: ""
});

let festivals = [];

data.forEach(festival => {

  const isDataMissing = !festival.num_voie && !festival.type_voie && !festival.nom_voie && !festival.complement_adresse;;

  if (isDataMissing) {
    return festivals.push({
      id: festival.identifiant,
      name: festival.Nom,
      url: festival.site_internet
    });
  } else {
    return;
  }
})

console.log(festivals.length)
// data.forEach( festival => {
//      return festivals.push({id: festival.identifiant, name: festival.Nom, url: festival.site_internet}) ;
// })


const scraper = async(festival) => {
  try {

    // puppeteer
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();;
    const page = (await browser.pages())[0];
    // await page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(0);
    // await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 1024 });
    await page.goto(festival.url)


    // cheerio
    const response = await axios.get(festival.url);
    const isDownloadable = await response.headers['content-disposition'] === undefined ? false : true;

    if (!isDownloadable) {

      const $ = await cheerio.load(response.data);
      let resultsLinks = await getLinks($, festival)
      console.log('RESULTS LINKS', resultsLinks)

      const image = await getScreenShot(festival, $, page, browser, 1000);
      festival.image = image;


      // get screenshot from interesting page on website

      if (resultsLinks.length > 0) {

        const imageUrls = await getPaths(resultsLinks, festival, browser)
        festival.images = imageUrls
        return festival

      } else {
        return festival;
      }

    } else {
      return festival.message = "Le contenu est téléchargeable, il ne peut pas être lu. "
    }


  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err, "Erreur au cours de la collecte de l'url du festival", festival.url, festival.name)
    return festival = {
      id: festival.id,
      name: festival.name,
      url: festival.url,
      image: [],
      images: [],
      message: `Erreur: ${err.message} : ${festival.url}`
    };
  }
}





// //   // routes

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {

  const scrapers = festivals.slice(0, 3).map(scraper);
  Promise.all(scrapers)
    .then(festivals => {

      // let data = {page: 1, data: festivals}
      // console.log(data)
      // fs.writeFileSync('result.json', JSON.stringify(data))
      console.log(festivals)

      res.status(200).json([{
        totalPage: festivals.length,
        data: festivals
      }])
    })

})


app.get('/results/', (req, res, next) => {
  const currentPage = Number(req.query.page) || 1;
  const lastPage = currentPage - 1;
  const perPage = 3;
  const totalFestival = Number(festivals.length);
  const totalPage = Math.ceil(totalFestival / perPage)
  const isLastPage = currentPage === totalPage ? true : false;
  let start = lastPage * perPage;
  let end = currentPage * perPage;

  const scrapers = festivals.slice(start, end).map(scraper);

  Promise.all(scrapers)
    .then(festivals => {
      console.log(festivals)
      res.status(200).json(festivals)
    })

})


app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('server is running'))

  ** // then the getSnapshot function **

  const getMatch = require('./getMatch')
const process = require('process')


const getScreenShot = async(festival, $, page, timeout) => {

  $('section,select,div,img,span,a,i,b,li,p,h1,h2,h3,h4').each(function() {
    let html = $.html($(this).clone().children().remove().end()); // html parent without children
    let text = $(this).clone().children().remove().end().text();
    const used = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1024 / 1024;
    console.log(process.memoryUsage())
    let match = getMatch(text);
    let textReplace = text;
    if (match.length > 0) {

      for (let i = 0; i < match.length; i++) {
        const regexMatch = new RegExp(match[i], 'g');
        textReplace = textReplace.replace(regexMatch, `<mark>${match[i]}</mark>`);
      }

      const replaceParent = $.html($(this).children().remove().end().html(textReplace))

    }

  })
  const idImage = festival.id + festival.name.normalize("NFD").replace(/[\u0300-\u036f]/g, "").replace("'", '').split(' ').join('') + Math.round(Math.random() * 10000) + '.jpg';
  const path = './images/' + idImage;

  await page.setContent($.html())
  await page.waitForTimeout(timeout)
  const image = await page.screenshot({
    path: path,
    fullPage: true
  })
  // const b64string = await page.screenshot({ encoding: "base64", fullPage: true })
  // const buffer = Buffer.from(b64string, "base64");
  await browser.close()

  return image;
}

module.exports = getScreenShot
```

Comment: This isn't exactly a [mcve], but the `scraper` function appears to leak a reference to a `browser` object that never gets closed if `if (resultsLinks.length > 0)` isn't true (the closure only happens if `getScreenShot` is called, which is probably not always). Use a `finally` block to make sure it's closed no matter what, and make your functions single-purpose, short and clean rather than allowing them to produce unrelated side effects and confusing control flow.

Comment: thank you for you response ! I check my code and the function getScreenshot is called before if (resultsLinks.length > 0) and in getScreenshot I close the browser object with  await browser.close(), or I did not understand   and in finally block should I return await browser.close then? I also forget to ask one thing, there is any way to clear the javascript memory it seem there is no more memory even if I cut the script and run a scraper smaller

Comment: I just ran this in my terminal in my backend  node -e 'console.log(v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit/(1024*1024))' and the terminal output is 2096. So maybe increase max-old-space-size did'nt work ?